# How can I get the 'Bird of Prey' achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

> "Destroy a ship at full health during a single cloak in the Stealth
>   Cruiser."

Using a 'Stealth Cruiser', full hull integrity at the end of the battle, just killed a ship in 2 rounds of lasers and beams, while the stealth was activated once.

Still didn't got the 'Birds of pray' achievement, what did I miss?

**UPDATE**

Reading the [Wiki - Bird of Prey](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Bird_of_Prey), it does say that:

> 'the ship must remain cloaked from the start of the volley until the
>   battle is over and the after-battle text pops up.'

I think the reason is that the ship just didn't last until the text and the cloak was done just before it :-(, well at least the mystery is solved.

Comment: Did your cloak wear off before the ship was destroyed?

Comment: Nope, clocked, attacked, ship destroyed, cloak barely made it, but ship exploded just in time.

Comment: Do i have to clock first? can I cloak after I started to fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this achievement you need to:

1. not fire any weapons before cloaking for the first time
2. activate cloaking
3. destroy the enemy ship before cloaking runs out

This achievement is far easier to get in the earlier sectors where enemy ships have weak shields and hulls. So when you hunt for this achievement you should prioritize upgrading cloaking and trying to pick up more weapons as early as possible. When you have the choice, pick up missiles. They usually have a higher damage output than other weapons to balance their ammo cost.

The easiest target to get this achievement are the unmanned drone-ships without shields. Your halberd-beam never misses and can hit 3 rooms dealing a guaranteed 6 hull damage.

When you found a potential target, wait until all your weapons have charged before you cloak. Cloak and perform the salvo. When your cloaking is already upgraded high enough and you have quick-recharging weapons, you might be able to get a second shot out of them before cloaking runs out.

Having the [Stealth Weapons](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Stealth_Weapons) augmentation helps, because it increases the chance to fire some weapons a second time before stealth runs out. Weapon pre-igniter doesn't help much because you can wait until all your weapons are charged before you cloak.

Answer (score 6):

You will need the '[Stealth Weapons](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Stealth_Weapons)' augmentation, that way you can cloak as a first action and then fire without disrupting your cloak.

The achievement is unlocked if you start your cloak when the enemy ship is at full health and you destroy it within a single cloak.

Comment: Obviously, having a 'Weapon Pre-Igniter' that lets you have readily available weapons just after the FTL jump, helps a lot... http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Weapon_Pre-Igniter

Comment: Great tips! The ship was in full health when I started the cloaking.

Comment: While the weapon Pre-Igniter is definitely a very useful augmentation for most playstyles, it doesn't help much in this case because you can wait until all your weapons are charged before cloaking. In the best case it prevents you from taking any hits which might take out any weapons or the cloaking system before you cloak.